# How open webview, when func in appdelegate is triggered?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, appdelegate

In appDelegate i have func, which receive Boolen, when app is opening.
If Boolen  == True, app must open webView.
How i can refer to viewcontroller, which initializes webView?
How create webview, which be see after app will receive the answer from server?

Thx.

//this is appDelegate file

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handled = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

       struct jsonR: Codable{ 
          let ads_enabled: Bool
        }
        print(url)


    Alamofire.request("https://appgootop.com))").responseJSON { response in

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            let product: jsonR = try! JSONDecoder().decode(jsonR.self, from: data)
            //print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
            print(product.ads_enabled)

            if product.ads_enabled == false{
                let url = URL(string: "google.com")!


                 }

            }
    }

    return handled
 }
```

Comment: what's the problem of the current code  ?

Comment: which line ?...

Comment: `webView` is nil ?

Comment: please clarify where are you initialize that webView?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class (UIViewController) that contains `WebView` and call it after your server return response.....

```swift
class WebViewContainer : UIViewController {
    open var link: String {
        didSet{ webView.request(link) }
    }

    let webView: UIWebView = {
        let webView =// initialize your webView here
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(webView)
        // add constraints here
    }
}
```

And use it after server response like this :

```swift
let webViewVC = WebViewContainer()
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
window.rootViewController = webViewVC
webViewVC.link = // assign your link here
```